# JavaScript onkeyup pass keyboard event from anchor

Tags: javascript, events

I have the following...

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onkeyup="my_func(e);">www.example.com</a>
```

I'm having trouble trying to get the event pass to the function. I get the following error in Firefox...

> ReferenceError: e is not defined

I simply need to access e.keyCode to determine if a specific key was pressed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onkeyup="my_func(e);">www.example.com</a>
```

to this

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onkeyup="my_func(event);">www.example.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked and I'll accept when the 10 minute bit passes.